# SQL calculate intermediate days

Tags: sql, teradata, between, days

suppose I have the following table and I am looking to extract the number of days between each positive and negative movement. 
In this way, then for each 'id' I have to calculate the intermediate days between each pair of dates and the proportion of the negative movement over the positive one, en SQL Teradata.

```
id   date  money
----------------
1    1-1   10
1    3-1   -5
1    9-1    8
1   10-1   -2
2    3-1   10
2    9-1  -10
2   15-1   20
2   19-1   -15


id  days_in prop
-----------------
1     2     0.5
1     1     0.25
2     6     1
2     4     0.75
```

Comment: may you can do a self join and check the difference. Not getting exactly what you need. You may have to explain the problem/output needed better way. Add name(table A and B) to the data you have in your question.

Comment: What column datatype are you using for the date column?  It looks above like it may be a string, but is it really a true datetime?

Comment: Yes, it would be a true datetime.

Comment: What if there are several consecutive rows with positive or negative values? What if there are two rows with the same date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
 select A.id, B.date - A.date as "days_in", (B.money - A.money)  / (b.date - A.date) 
 as "prop"
 from
 (
    select X.id, X.date, min(NextDate.date) as "MinNextDate", X.money
    from [yourTable] X, [yourtable] NextDate
    where
    NextDate.date > X.date
    and NextDate.id = X.id
 ) A,
[YourTable] B
where
   A.id = B.id
   and B.date = A.MinNextDate
```

I think that teradata returns a date difference as a number of days in integer format.  If it is a dateTime, you may need to case the datetime values to dates before subtracting.

Comment: There's a GROUP BY missing in the Derived Table. And depending on the number of rows per id this might need lots of CPU due to the non-equi-join.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a self join in a slightly different way, however it wil still produce extra rows since the join will be done with each row.. you can further restrict it based on your criteria

```
select a.id, (b.date-a.date) as days_in,
abs(b.money)/a.money as prop
from <table> a
inner join <table> b
on a.id=b.id
and a.date<>b.date
where (b.date-a.date)>0 and (abs(b.money)/a.money)>0
and (a.money>0 and b.money<=-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the previous positive value you can use `last_value`:

```
SELECT id
  ,datecol
  -- ratio between current negative and previous positive money
  ,Abs(Cast(money AS NUMBER)) /
   Last_Value(CASE WHEN money > 0 THEN money end IGNORE NULLS)
   Over (PARTITION BY id
         ORDER BY datecol)
  -- difference between current and previous date
  -- might need a cast to date or interval result if the datecol is a Timestamp
  ,datecol-
   Last_Value(CASE WHEN money > 0 THEN DATE_ end IGNORE NULLS)
   Over (PARTITION BY id
         ORDER BY datecol)
FROM vt AS t
-- return only rows with negative money
QUALIFY money < 0
```

Of course, this assumes there are always alternate rows with positive & negative values.